# A traits class for (compound) pointers - beyond what std::pointer_traits offers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17

This is a percolation of ideas which originated this SO question:

[Compound pointer traits class with method generalizing make_shared and make_unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506521/)

The [`std::pointer_traits` class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits) offers the following traits, basically:

Types: `pointer`, `element_type`, `difference_type`, and `rebind` (given a pointer-like type for pointing to `T`, get a pointer-like type for pointing to `U`)

Static methods:

- `to_address` - get the plain vanilla T* from some fancy pointer-to-T-like class, if possible
- `pointer_to` - opposite of `to_address`. This is a fishy method, since it's not clear what it means with respect to resource ownership.

I think it's useful to add at least two methods - for creating a pointer to a new object / array of objects, a-la `std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique`, and one for releasing ownership + getting the raw address. Here's my implementation:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef EXTRA_POINTER_TRAITS_HPP_
#define EXTRA_POINTER_TRAITS_HPP_

#include <memory>

template <typename Ptr>
struct extra_pointer_traits;

template <typename T>
struct extra_pointer_traits<T*>
{
    using ptr_type = T*;
    using element_type = T;

    static ptr_type make(size_t count) { return new T[count]; }
    static ptr_type make()             { return new T;        }
};

template <typename T>
struct extra_pointer_traits<T[]>
{
    using ptr_type = T[];
    using element_type = T;

    static T* make(size_t count) { return new T[count]; }
    static T* make()             { return new T;        }
};

template <typename T, class Deleter>
struct extra_pointer_traits<std::unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>>
{
    using ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>;
    using element_type = T;

    static T* release(ptr_type& ptr) { return ptr.release(); }
    static std::unique_ptr<T[], Deleter> make(size_t count)
    {
        return std::make_unique<T[]>(count);
    }
};


template <typename T, class Deleter>
struct extra_pointer_traits<std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>>
{
    using ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>;
    using element_type = T;

    static T* release(ptr_type& ptr) { return ptr.release(); }
    static std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter> make()
    {
        return std::make_unique<T>();
    }
};


template <typename T>
struct extra_pointer_traits<std::shared_ptr<T>>
{
    using ptr_type = std::shared_ptr<T>;
    using element_type = typename std::pointer_traits<ptr_type>::element_type;

    // No release()
    static std::shared_ptr<element_type[]> make(size_t count)
    {
        return std::make_shared<element_type[]>(count);
    }
    static std::shared_ptr<element_type> make()
    {
        return std::make_shared<element_type>();
    }
};

#endif // EXTRA_POINTER_TRAITS_HPP_
```

I'm considering suggesting something like this as an *addition* to the existing traits class the standards committe, but for now I've implemented it as a separate class.

**Note:** To clarify - these are not all possible template specializations for pointer-like classes in the standard library, there would be a few more.

Comment: I tried to suggest an idea to the committee but faced quite a lot of questions I didn't think of. They're also busy with all of those concepts, contracts, modules, executors, etc. I'm not saying that pushing an idea through committee is impossible, but it is extremely hard (at least for a student of my age and experience).

Comment: 1. Can you link to where those questions where raised? If not, perhaps put it in a pastebin? 2. If they're busy, that's fine. I mean, it's not fine, but it's not something wrong with the suggestion. 3. It may be extremely hard to push something through committee but it's much harder if you don't try :-)

Comment: Do you have an email? I can forward you the whole chain, because they operate using mailing lists ...

Answer (score 5):

First, `size_t` should be `std::size_t` everywhere.

Why don't the raw pointer/array cases have `release()`? Granted, it won't really change any ownership in reality, but it could conceptually.

```
static ptr_type make(size_t count) { return new T[count]; }
static ptr_type make()             { return new T;        }
```

I'm not sure this interface is a good idea as is. This only supports `T`s with default constructors. What about constructor arguments:

```
template <typename... Args>
static ptr_type make(Args&&... args)
{
    return new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

But of course, if you do that, it conflicts with the `make(std::size_t)` overload. So you'd need a different name for that, like `make_n()` or something, maybe with an interface like:

```
template <typename... Args>
static ptr_type make_n(std::size_t count, Args&&... args)
{
    return new T[count]{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

However, what about the difference between `T{...}` and `T(...)`? Now you need overloads for those cases, too.

Now, as for the overall idea, I'm not a committee member, but I can tell you with absolute certainty that this will never be accepted.

First, what *actual* problem in use is this supposed to solve? What is an actual use case where this is necessary and offers a significant improvement? I can't think of any situation where this will be useful. Certainly not one that's generalizable, which is mandatory for a standard library addition.

Generally speaking, memory management should be handled by containers, and containers use allocators, and this has no allocator support whatsoever.

Even worse, it *hides* the allocation method from client code... which is disastrous because you need to know how something was allocated to know how to DEallocate it. As it is, your interface offers a "handy" way to allocate memory, but no way to free it, and in fact goes out of its way to make code *less* safe by stripping ownership from smart pointers with the `release()` function.

In summary, I see no general gain from this, and plenty of dangerous drawbacks.

Comment: One could also use `make_many_tag`, or some other tag type to ensure that the right overload is called.

Comment: @Incomputable: So you'd propose four overloads (`make(with_braces_tag, Args&&...)`, `make(with_parens_tag, Args&&...)`, `make(array_with_braces_tag, size_t, Args&&...)` and `make(array_with_parens_tag, size_t, Args&&...)`)? If I'd have to use a tag for every possible overload, I'd prefer differently named functions unless there is a very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @hoffmale, well. I thought about dropping support for braces. But you're right, that would still be inferior to differently named functions.

Comment: 1. "Why don't the raw pointer/array cases have `release()`?" You mean, a `release()` which does nothing? I think that would be more confusing than helpful; but maybe you can convince me otherwise. 2. Good point about construction with arguments. `make_unique()` and `make_shared()` have that, and so should I.

Comment: About the general point: This traits class will simply allow the same piece of code to work for shared ptr's, unique_ptr's, my_custom_unique_ptr_like_t and so on - and do allocations (and perhaps releases, although that's trickier).

Comment: @einpoklum I get that "allowing code to work with different pointer types" is the intention, but that isn't a use case. That intention could be satisfied a number of different ways (not least being exactly what you did, without merging with `pointer_traits` or standardizing). You need a use case showing why *this* solution is best, and why it might be *generally* useful, not a vague statement of intention.

Comment: @indi: Yes, that's true, but it's not something I would put here on codereview.SX.

Comment: @einpoklum It seems to me that if what you want reviewed is whether some bit of code is generally useful, a general use case is a perfectly legitimate thing to expect. Even if it's not for *general* use, when offering functions or classes for review, a sample of the usage of the function or class is *very* helpful in reviewing it. *Especially* for reviewing its interface.

Comment: @Incomputable Oh, and BTW, the reason I didn't propose tags is because that would make it more annoying to use in the case where the `T` constructor also takes those tags. You'd have to do `make(many_tag, many_tag, /*...*/)`, and if you do `make(many_tag, /*...*/);` it may silently work but not do what you want. It didn't seem worth the annoyance and risk when differently-named functions works just as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm with you that `std::pointer_traits` and C++ standard library smart pointers in general have some drawbacks (e.g. ownership semantics of `pointer_to`) that might need to be addressed.

That said, I don't think that this implementation is working towards that goal:

- Memory management: Different forms of `extra_pointer_traits<T>::make` acquire pointers to memory, but most specializations have no way to release said memory (and the `std::unique_ptr` one only releases ownership, not the backing memory).

  This is no "trivial" problem, either: When given a `T*` (allocated using one of the overloads of `extra_pointer_traits<T*>::make`), do you know whether to call `delete` or `delete[]` on it?

  And this is just the tip of the iceberg: Once allocators enter the picture there is no general way of keeping track how to delete every pointer without somehow storing a reference to the allocator with each pointer.
- Uniformity: There's no clear standard feature set. Some specializations provide `make()`, others provide `make(size_t)`, some provide `release()` - but there is no easy way (other than failure of compilation) to query which operations are actually available.

  For example: You cannot simply call `make()`, as `extra_pointer_traits<std::unique_ptr<T[], Deleter>>` doesn't provide it.
- Trait deduction: Most standard library traits have an ability to deduce traits from any type as long as said type adheres to some interface (e.g. `std::iterator_traits` automatically gives the correct traits if a class implements `value_type`, `pointer`, `reference`, `difference_type` and `iterator_category`).

  There doesn't seem to be an easy way to generally deduce `make()` or similar for any custom pointer-like type.
- Object construction: Ignoring the memory release problems mentioned above, some types simply don't have a default constructor (or any `public` constructors, for that matter), which means `extra_pointer_traits<PointerType>::make` overloads now compile conditionally not only on the pointer type itself, but also on the pointees type. This seems counter-intuitive on a trait that should be as general as possible.

  > Yes, some of these problems (non-default constructors) could be overcome with perfect forwarding of parameters, but others (non-`public` constructors, `T(...)` vs `T{...}`) are unsolvable (without modifying the pointee) or require additional design space (e.g. special functions for `make_array`, `make_with_braces`, `make_with_parens`, ...).
  >
  > Then you'd again need special handling for some cases, e.g. if the pointee is of type `void` (possibly cv-qualified). This means you get an combinatorial explosion of specializations (number of pointer-like types times types requiring soecial handling).
- Ownership semantics: `extra_pointer_trais<T>::make` overloads always create a new owning pointer - even for pointer types (e.g. raw pointers) that don't have any concrete ownership semantics associated with themselves. This is just waiting for ownership conflicts (and all the surrounding problems, e.g. memory leaks, use-after-free, dangling pointers, ...) to happen.
- Incomplete specializations: `std::weak_ptr` as another standard library pointer-like type is missing, as are `std::shared_ptr<T[]>` (which might be different from `std::shared_ptr<T>`) and `T[N]`.

  > Also, specializations for `const` and `volatile` qualified pointer-like types are missing. What specialization would be used for a `const std::unique_ptr<T>`? What about `const volatile T* const volatile`?
- Allocator support: Most of the time, the standard library goes out of its way to allow users to bring their own allocators, which allows for some cool features that would otherwise be unavailable (e.g. control over memory allocations at an overarching level, relocatable heaps or tracing object collection). There is currently no support for allocators inside `extra_pointer_traits`.

As glimpsed from this overview, the implementation introduces more problems than it solves (and the latter would have to be defined more clearly, as it currently is far too vague and open to interpretation).

As long as these points remain unaddressed (no pun intended), I can't see any committee approving of this.

> ## Food for thoughts:
>
> There are several orthogonal concerns that pointers have to deal with:
>
> - Allocation: How is memory acquired and released?
> - Lifetime: What object is at that pointer referring to?
> - Ownership: When does the memory get acquired/released and who is responsible for doing so?
> - Representation (aka address model): How is the pointer value represented in memory? Examples: An address (raw pointer), an offset (e.g. `boost::offset_ptr`) or segmented (16 bit `far` pointers).
>
> Some of my personal gripes with the standard library arise from the fact that these concerns are not cleanly separated, e.g.
>
> - allocators have to deal with types instead of just managing memory (mixing of allocation and lifetime concerns). This makes it hard to reuse allocators for different types, and tightly couples them to the implementation of the type that might be placed in the allocated memory.
> - `std::shared_ptr` by itself is only usable with raw pointer representation (mixing ownership, representation and lifetime). There's no way to have a `shared_ptr` contain a `boost::offset_ptr` internally, or to know whether the object being pointed to is actually initialized.
> - `std::unique_ptr` is slightly better off: It can be used with arbitrary pointer representations (via `Deleter::pointer`), but it is hard to do so. It still mixes ownership and lifetime, though: There will be problems with a `std::unique_ptr<T>` (with `T` not being `void`) referring to uninitialized memory upon assignment/destruction.
>
> The `extra_pointer_traits` implementation goes beyond that: It mixes allocation, ownership and lifetime concerns, and does so in a fashion that none of those concerns are fully realized.

Comment: Specific points, followed by a more general one: 1. Incomplete specializations: Should definitely add them, I should have mentioned the existing ones are just some important examples. 2. Allocators - wouldn't your criticism apply to `std::make_unique()` and `std::make_shared` as well?

Comment: As for allocators - I don't think this class should involve itself with them, in the same was that `make_unique()` and `make_shared()` don't. You can write a pointer-like class templated on an allocator and use its `make()` and `release()` traits I suppose.

Comment: The more general point is, that without these traits you have a small jumble of freestanding functions and methods of the pointer-like types in the language and the standard library. But with them, you have a better-organized jumble, which is easy(er) to extend if you write your own pointer-like classes.

Comment: @einpoklum: `std::allocate_shared` is the allocator-supporting version of `std::make_shared`. Yes, there is no explicit `std::allocate_unique` equivalent for `std::unique_ptr`, but that doesn't mean `std::unique_ptr` cannot be used with allocators: `std::unique_ptr` can be initialized from an already constructed pointer, and the custom deleter can use the allocator for deallocation.

Comment: @einpoklum: Re jumble of functions: An unusable set of better organized functions cannot replace a jumble of usable freestanding functions. The problems with freeing memory make this "better organized" jumble unusable. And that is no easy problem to solve: if a `T*` was allocated with an allocator, you cannot simply `delete` or `delete[]` it. Allocators are a tool with a purpose: Unifying memory acquisition and release in a well understood interface. Any attempt at providing "better" memory management facilities needs to show how they are better than allocators, or be able to make use of them.

Comment: @einpoklum: I added some of my thoughts on the subject matter to my answer, in hope of clarifying what my issues with the implementation are and why I care so much about certain specific concerns.